# Lots of Loops, Lots of Questions

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've written this code. It seems to run correctly through the first set of nested for loops. When I put in debugger above the final for loop, it will return the correct thing for me (and if I want to return newArray, it will return). What am I doing wrong?

I want it to loop through the letterSplit array I've made of the input, then loop through the values array and find the corresponding value, and push that corresponding value into the newArray. This works so far with 1 letter.

BUT I also want it to work for multiple letters, so that if someone puts in "cat", it will add them all up into a new array "total". That is what I was trying to do with the last for loop. Suggestions? Ideas? Do you see a misplaced word or character somewhere?

```
var scrabble = function (letter) {
var newLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
var letterSplit = newLetter.split(" ");
var newArray = [];
var stupidArray = [];
var total = 0;
var values = [["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1],
                ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10]];

    for (var i=0; i < letterSplit.length; i++) {
        for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] === letterSplit[0]) {
            newArray.push(values[i][1]);
            stupidArray += letterSplit.splice(0,1);
            }
        } 
    } 
     for (var i=0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        total += i;
    }

var result = total.toString();
return total;
};
```

Comment: FWIW: `x += y` -> x is *not* an array afterwards

Comment: You are splitting the string on spaces: `newLetter.split(" ");`, thus it will split up `a cat` into `['a','cat']` but not into letters. You should just do `newLetter.split('')`.

Comment: What is this code meant to do, exactly? Find the score for a given word, or something?

Comment: christian - you're right! I changed it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: user2864740 - thank you! Then I just tried to return total by itself, but got nothing. Total would be a number already, correct? It's still returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code corrected

Javascript

```
var scrabble = function (letter) {
    var letterSplit = letter.toLowerCase().split(''),
        total = 0,
        values = [
            ['a', 1],
            ['b', 3],
            ['c', 3],
            ['d', 2],
            ['e', 1],
            ['f', 4],
            ['g', 2],
            ['h', 4],
            ['i', 1],
            ['j', 8],
            ['k', 5],
            ['l', 1],
            ['m', 3],
            ['n', 1],
            ['o', 1],
            ['p', 3],
            ['q', 10],
            ['r', 1],
            ['s', 1],
            ['t', 1],
            ['u', 1],
            ['v', 4],
            ['w', 4],
            ['x', 8],
            ['y', 4],
            ['z', 10]
        ],
        i,
        j;

    for (i = 0; i < letterSplit.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (values[j][0] === letterSplit[i]) {
                total += values[j][1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return total;
};

console.log(scrabble('cat'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/j5W4u/)

Comment: THANK YOU! That was exactly it, that I was using the same variable for both for loops! I knew it was something little that I wasn't seeing, or something I didn't know. I've not nested for loops before, so I didn't even think about it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using an `Object` as a lookup for the letter value would probably be simpler/more sensible. Something like this.

Javascript

```
var values = {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
    c: 3,
    d: 2,
    e: 1,
    f: 4,
    g: 2,
    h: 4,
    i: 1,
    j: 8,
    k: 5,
    l: 1,
    m: 3,
    n: 1,
    o: 1,
    p: 3,
    q: 10,
    r: 1,
    s: 1,
    t: 1,
    u: 1,
    v: 4,
    w: 4,
    x: 8,
    y: 4,
    z: 10
};

function scrabble(word) {
    return word.toLowerCase().split('').reduce(function (acc, letter) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
            acc += values[letter];
        }

        return acc;
    }, 0);
}

console.log(scrabble('cat'));
```

Output

```
5
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qrv9q/)

Comment: Thanks! Everyone wants to solve this with an object, but I need to solve it with an array. I really think my code is close, and it's bothering me that there's gotta be some little thing not making it work!

Comment: Just simply `reduce` the `array` to an `object`.

Comment: In your solution you use the index iterator `i` as the variable name for both the inner and outer `for` loops. And you should `split` all characters, not on a space.

Comment: @Magpie: why do you need to solve it with an array? I'm not intending to criticise, but it's not a cheap approach given that it involves looping partway through the array testing each element.